# Despite public Inheritance and public Base Class Constructor, the Derived Class has no access to its parent's constructor

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, visual-studio-2015

I have a Base Class named "*GroupBoxWidget*" and two children named "*GroupBoxIn*" and "*GroupBoxOut*". Both of them try to construct themselves using its parent as an initialisation. At this point the IntelliSense says that the *CGroupBox*'s constructor is inaccessible.

Let's see that in details, shall we? Beginning with the parent...

**GroupBoxWidget.h**

```
#ifndef MY_GROUPBOX_H
#define MY_GROUPBOX_H
#include <QGroupBox>
class CGroupBoxWidget: public QGroupBox
{
public:
    Q_OBJECT
    CGroupBoxWidget(QWidget* pParent = nullptr);
    virtual ~CGroupBoxWidget();
protected:
    //Create Widgets
    virtual QGroupBox *CreateBtnsGroupBox() = 0;
private:

};

#endif // !MY_GROUPBOX_H
```

As you can see, the *QGroupBoxWidget* itself is derived from *QGroupBox* from Qt's library. Nothing is declared as private. The pure virtual function "=0" will be overriden in the children. Let's take a fast look into it's constructor in **GroupBoxWidget.cpp**:

```
//Constructor
CGroupBoxWidget::CGroupBoxWidget(QWidget* pParent) : QGroupBox(pParent)
{
    //Every MainGroupBoxWidget integrates at least two Labels, a ComboBox and a PushButton
}
```

Let's now choose a child to examinate. Looking at **GroupBoxIn.h**:

```
#ifndef GROUPBOXIN_H
#define GROUPBOXIN_H
#include "GroupBoxWidget.h"
class CGroupBoxIn : public CGroupBoxWidget
{
public:
    Q_OBJECT
    CGroupBoxIn(QWidget* pParent = nullptr);
    virtual ~CGroupBoxIn(); 

protected:

    virtual QGroupBox *CreateBtnsGroupBox() override;
    QButtonGroup *m_pButtonGroupIn;

private:

};
#endif // !GROUPBOXIN_H
```

Everything is okay here. The pure virtual function overrides the one from the base's class. But when I try to construct it in the **GroupBoxIn.cpp** I got a fine red line below the Initialization List through the parent class exactly at

> *CGroupBoxWidgetidget(pParent)*

```
CGroupBoxIn::CGroupBoxIn(QWidget* pParent) : CGroupBoxWidget(pParent)
{   this->setTitle("Input"); }
```

I would like to hear your suggestions about from where this compiler error comes from.

> Error C2248   'CGroupBoxWidget::CGroupBoxWidget': cannot access private
> member declared in class 'CGroupBoxWidget'    Build

I'm using MSVC 15, Qt 5.8, C++11 and Windows 11.

Comment: Is the error from intellisense or the compiler? If its just intellisense then report a bug to microsoft and ignore the error. If its the compiler please provide the full text of the compiler output

Comment: "A fine red line below" is not how compilers reject ill-formed C++ code. Now, try to compile the shown code, and see what happens. C++ is just too complicated, and only a C++ compiler can fully understand all C++ source code. Your text editor, which draws these red lines, is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: Note that Qt code is not directly edible for C++ compiler; that framework uses extended C++ language and so the source code typically needs special preprocessing for to compile. Probably your IDE tries to crunch it directly using its own limited knowledge of C++ and becomes confused.

Comment: @ÖöTiib the code should be valid c++, the custom keywords are defined as macros

Comment: @AlanBirtles Note that the macros may refer to code generated subsequently by `moc` and hence not visible to intellisense.  Not sure if that's the issue here though.

Comment: You might struggle editing Qt using Visual Studio. Can you bring it up in Qt Creator and see what he does?

Comment: Please show the full text of the compiler output not the summary from the error list